# Java substring string when specific string occurs

Tags: java, string, substring

i need help to substring a string when a a substring occurs.
Example

> Initial string: 123456789abcdefgh
>
> string to substr: abcd
>
> result : 123456789

I checked substr method but it accept index position value.I need to search the occurrence of the substring and than pass the index?

Comment: You need to check the javadoc a bit longer. Everything you need is right there ... hint: some of those methods exist in more than one flavor.

Comment: Yes , i need to search occurrence first with IndexOf method
String before = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(substr));

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the String from the last number (a), then the code would look like this:

> you can change the `"a"` to any char within the string

```
package nl.testing.startingpoint;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] part = getSplitArray("123456789abcdefgh", "a");

        System.out.println(part[0]);
        System.out.println(part[1]);
    }

    public static String[] getSplitArray(String toSplitString, String spltiChar) {
        return toSplitString.split("(?<=" + spltiChar + ")");
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that `toSplitString.split("(?<=" + spltiChar  + ")");` splits from the first occurrence of that character.

Comment: No, i need to find also other position like (bcde)

Comment: @AlessioDiMarco, edited the code, just change the char `"a"` to any char within the string you want to split on!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    searchString("123456789abcdefghabcd", "abcd");
}

public static void searchString(String inputValue, final String searchValue)
{
    while (!(inputValue.indexOf(searchValue) < 0))
    {
        System.out.println(inputValue.substring(0, inputValue.indexOf(searchValue)));

        inputValue = inputValue.substring(inputValue.indexOf(searchValue) +
            searchValue.length());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
123456789
efgh
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression, like this

```
static String regex = "[abcd[.*]]"

public String remove(String string, String regex) {
    return string.contains(regex) ? string.replaceAll(regex) : string;
}
```